# Getting only selected date in bootstrap-date paginator

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-datepaginator [Source](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator).

The below code returns date in this format `Sun Aug 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400`

Instead of that i want to return it in this format `14/Aug/2016`

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var options = {
                selectedDate: '2016-01-01',
                selectedDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }

            $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);

            $('#paginator').datepaginator();

            $('#paginator').on('selectedDateChanged', function (event, date) {
                // Your logic goes here
                alert(date);
            });
        });</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
               "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Ntove", "Dec" ];


var dati = "Sun Aug 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400";


var date = new Date(dati);
var thedate = date.getDate();
var themonth = date.getMonth();
var theyear = date.getFullYear();

alert(thedate);
alert(themonth);
alert(theyear);

var newdate = thedate +"/"+months[themonth]+"/"+theyear;
alert(newdate);
```

working example

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>



</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
               "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Ntove", "Dec" ];


var dati = "Sun Aug 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400";


var date = new Date(dati);
var thedate = date.getDate();
var themonth = date.getMonth();
var theyear = date.getFullYear();

alert(thedate);
alert(themonth);
alert(theyear);

var newdate = thedate +"/"+months[themonth]+"/"+theyear;
alert(newdate);







</script>

</html>
```