# How to format a date time with timezone in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How to format date returned from server in this format

`2016-08-17T11:17:57+04:00` in human readable format - for example

`17-08-2016, 11:17 AM`

in jquery?

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946698/changing-date-time-format-using-jquery-javascript/23948956#23948956) but the problem is that its always converting the time in IST. Even people from US is also seeing this in IST. Not quite getting what is the problem.

Tried this but the problem still persists.

[Changing Date Time Format using jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946698/changing-date-time-format-using-jquery-javascript/23948956#23948956)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275696/javascript-format-date-time http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/kqo10jLb/4/

Comment: Maybe this topic will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format

Comment: new Date("2016-08-17T11:17:57+04:00")  - you have .toLocaleDateString and toLocaleTimeString

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting the date time with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847109/formatting-the-date-time-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

try this [Getting only selected date in bootstrap-date paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000855/getting-only-selected-date-in-bootstrap-date-paginator/39001182#39001182)

if you do not want the month from name, just keep the month value,not the name

more additionally, I think this is what you want
to get the date try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 

 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var datestring = "2016-08-17T11:17:57+04:00";
  var mydate = new Date(datestring);
  var thedate = mydate.getDate();
  var month = mydate.getMonth();
  var year = mydate.getFullYear();
 


 
  var theresult = year +"-"+"0"+(month+1)+"-"+thedate;
  alert(theresult);

   

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: When i'm running this snippet i'm getting 17-08-2016, 12:47 as result.  But I want 2016-08-17, 11:17:57

Comment: is this date auto generated like `new Date()` or a date by given you

Comment: This date is given by me.

Comment: can't you give it in this format `Thu Aug 18 2016 15:52:24 GMT+0530 (IST)`

Answer (score 0):

Version 1:

```js
function pad(num) {
  return String("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function formatDate(d) {
   day = d.getDate();
 month = d.getMonth()+1,
  year = d.getFullYear();
  return ""+pad(day)+"-"+pad(month)+"-"+year+" "+d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
var d = new Date("2016-08-17T11:17:57+04:00");
console.log(formatDate(d));
```

version 2:

```js
function chopString(d) {
  var parts = d.split("T");
  return parts[0] + " " + parts[1].split("+")[0];
}
console.log(chopString("2016-08-17T11:17:57+04:00"));
```